# A correct Latin translation of "By the power of will, I, while living, conquered the universe"?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

I wanted to change the sentence Vi veri universum vivus vici (By the power of truth, I, while living, conquered the universe) to Vi voluntatis universum vivus vici (By the power of will, I, while living, conquered the universe) Is Vi voluntatis universum vivus vici the right choice?

I would like to ask what would be a more natural translation of this sentence?
(By the power of will, I, while living, conquered the universe)

Keeping the structure of the original sentence, I want to emphasise the power of the will instead of the truth.

Answer (score 2):

Both *veri* and *voluntatis* are the same case (genitive), so yes, you've correctly substituted the latter for the former.

Edit: misread the direction of the translation. It's a fine translation into Latin.

Comment: cmw: The OP has translated eleven words of English into five words of Latin; therefore, why do you describe this as "a bit clumsy"? What should it be? What's the difference between "power of will" & "force of will"?

Comment: @tony I meant the English is clumsy. Not overly so.

Comment: With 4 hours of work I changed the original quote in two different ways: (I conquered the universe by my will) and (I conquered the universe by the power of my will) because it is simpler and easier to understand.
First quote translation = (Voluntate mea universum vici) 
Second quoted translation = (Universum vi voluntatis meae vici.) 
Do you think there is a better translation or is there something wrong with my translation?
note: i am a beginner in latin language

Comment: @efmh You don't really need to add *mea/meae*; it could be understood from context. You get the all Vs if you drop it. You've got the grammar of the Latin exactly right. No need to change that.